# How to create an instance from a DataTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, datatemplate

I have implemented a custom control that internally uses a ListView within the control template. This ListView is accessable by FindParts. I need to set the ListViews View property to an instance that I have to instanciate programmatically within my custom control. I want to be able to create this instance from a DataTemplate that can be bound to a property of my custom control.

The problem is that I do not know how to create an instance from a DataTemplate.

Note that I do not want to bind a GridView directly to the View property (e.g. from a ResourceDictionary where the DataTemplates x:Shared attribute is set to false) as this leads to problems in the XAML designer (View can't be shared by more than one ListView).

**Edit:** Durig my discussion with grek40 it became clear that it is not possible to provide the GridView within a DataTemplate. Thus the answer marked as solution does not handle the question how to create an instance from a DataTemplate as implied by the title of my question.

Comment: I get the feeling that you are slightly off track at some point. [`ListView.View`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listview.view(v=vs.110).aspx) is of type `ViewBase` so if you want to pass this part from the outside into your CustomControl, you need a property of this type. Maybe some sample code would help to understand where you want the `DataTemplate` in this whole thing.

Comment: Yes, you are right. At the moment I have a DependencyProperty of type ViewBase. In a ResourceDictionary I have Resources for that property and Styles with a Setter to assign those Resources. As I mentioned above I had to set x:Shared=false in order to get those Resources to be usable at RunTime but they lead to problems at design time. I now want to change my control to accept a DataTemplate that contains the definition of the GridView. The control then needs to create an instance of the DataTemplate. My question is how to create an instance from a DataTemplate.

Comment: Is there a reason you're not just binding the listview's itemsource and Itemtemplate?

Comment: The control is an AutoCompleteLookup. It can be styled to support different data types. When the suggestions are displayed the items can be shown with columns. For some data types it will show only one column, for others there can be multiple. In order to be able to define the various columns I must be able to exchange the Listviews view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you didn't share much code, I made something out of thin air. The Idea: `MyCustomControl` is hosting items and for that, a `ListView` is used in the `ControlTemplate`. A default `GridView` is included directly in the `ControlTemplate` but it's possible to change it via `MyCustomControl.MyView`

The Custom Control:

```
public class MyCustomControl : ItemsControl
{
    static MyCustomControl()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(MyCustomControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(MyCustomControl)));
    }


    public ViewBase MyView
    {
        get { return (ViewBase)GetValue(MyViewProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MyViewProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty MyViewProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("MyView", typeof(ViewBase), typeof(MyCustomControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, new PropertyChangedCallback(OnMyViewChanged)));

    private static void OnMyViewChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ((MyCustomControl)d).HasCustomView = e.NewValue != null;
    }



    // readonly property to support the Trigger in the ControlTemplate in order to exchange the ListView.View
    public bool HasCustomView
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(HasCustomViewProperty); }
        private set { SetValue(HasCustomViewPropertyKey, value); }
    }

    private static readonly DependencyPropertyKey HasCustomViewPropertyKey =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterReadOnly("HasCustomView", typeof(bool), typeof(MyCustomControl), new PropertyMetadata(false));
    public static readonly DependencyProperty HasCustomViewProperty = HasCustomViewPropertyKey.DependencyProperty;
}
```

The Control Template (note the default GridView and the Trigger for Replacement):

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:MyCustomControl}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:MyCustomControl}">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                    <ListView x:Name="PART_ListView"
                              ItemsSource="{Binding Items,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}">
                        <ListView.View>
                            <GridView>
                                <GridView.Columns>
                                    <GridViewColumn Header="DEF"/>
                                </GridView.Columns>
                            </GridView>
                        </ListView.View>
                    </ListView>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="HasCustomView" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="PART_ListView" Property="View" Value="{Binding MyView,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Usage:

```
<local:MyCustomControl>
    <!--uses default view-->
    <TextBlock Text="Item 1"/>
    <TextBlock Text="Item 2"/>
</local:MyCustomControl>

<local:MyCustomControl>
    <!--uses custom view-->
    <local:MyCustomControl.MyView>
        <GridView>
            <GridView.Columns>
                <GridViewColumn Header="ABC"/>
            </GridView.Columns>
        </GridView>
    </local:MyCustomControl.MyView>
    <TextBlock Text="Item 1"/>
    <TextBlock Text="Item 2"/>
</local:MyCustomControl>
```

Feel free to ask if anything remains unclear. As commented, I don't know how to apply your `DataTemplate` idea to all this stuff.

**Edit:**

The following is a an example with resource section to define some data and `DataTemplate`s as well as their possible usage.

```
<StackPanel>
    <StackPanel.Resources>
        <x:Array x:Key="Items1" Type="{x:Type sys:Int32}">
            <sys:Int32>1</sys:Int32>
            <sys:Int32>2</sys:Int32>
            <sys:Int32>3</sys:Int32>
            <sys:Int32>4</sys:Int32>
        </x:Array>

        <x:Array x:Key="Items2" Type="{x:Type sys:Int32}">
            <sys:Int32>5</sys:Int32>
            <sys:Int32>4</sys:Int32>
            <sys:Int32>6</sys:Int32>
            <sys:Int32>7</sys:Int32>
        </x:Array>

        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="ItemsSource1" Source="{StaticResource Items1}"/>
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="ItemsSource2" Source="{StaticResource Items2}"/>

        <DataTemplate x:Key="IntegerListTemplate1">
            <local:MyCustomControl ItemsSource="{Binding}">
                <!--uses default view-->
            </local:MyCustomControl>
        </DataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate x:Key="IntegerListTemplate2">
            <local:MyCustomControl ItemsSource="{Binding}">
                <!--uses custom view-->
                <local:MyCustomControl.MyView>
                    <GridView>
                        <GridView.Columns>
                            <GridViewColumn Header="ABC"/>
                        </GridView.Columns>
                    </GridView>
                </local:MyCustomControl.MyView>
            </local:MyCustomControl>
        </DataTemplate>
    </StackPanel.Resources>
    <!--the default view-->
    <ContentControl ContentTemplate="{StaticResource IntegerListTemplate1}" Content="{Binding Source={StaticResource ItemsSource1}}"/>
    <Separator Margin="3"/>
    <!--same items other view-->
    <ContentControl ContentTemplate="{StaticResource IntegerListTemplate2}" Content="{Binding Source={StaticResource ItemsSource1}}"/>
    <Separator Margin="3"/>
    <!--different items same view as second one, no complaints about reusing-->
    <ContentControl ContentTemplate="{StaticResource IntegerListTemplate2}" Content="{Binding Source={StaticResource ItemsSource2}}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

**Edit 2, targeting the commented MCVE:**

I would solve this exactly as I already explained in my first edit. Turn your control into a `DataTemplate`, not the view into a style.

Replace in MainWindow.xaml:

```
<!-- old -->
<myctrls:MyControl Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Style="{StaticResource AddressStyle}" ItemsSource="{Binding Addresses}"/>
<!-- new -->
<ContentControl Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource AddressTemplate}" Content="{Binding Addresses}"/>
```

Same with the other occurences.

In MyControlStyles.xaml (or a renamed file that indicates `DataTemplate` usage), merge the `GridView` resource and the `Style` with the `myctrls:MyControl` into a `DataTemplate`.

Old:

```
<GridView x:Key="AddressGridView" x:Shared="False">
    <GridViewColumn Header="City" Width="Auto" >
        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding City}" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn>
    <GridViewColumn Header="Country" Width="Auto" >
        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Country}" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn>
</GridView>

<Style x:Key="AddressStyle" TargetType="{x:Type myctrls:MyControl}">
    <Setter Property="SuggestionsView" Value="{DynamicResource AddressGridView}"/>
</Style>
```

New:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="AddressTemplate">
    <!-- the base control -->
    <myctrls:MyControl ItemsSource="{Binding}">
        <!-- this was previously assigned by AddressStyle -->
        <myctrls:MyControl.SuggestionsView>
            <!-- this was previously the AddressGridView -->
            <!-- Same as before, only removed the x:Key and x:Shared -->
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="City" Width="Auto" >
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding City}" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Country" Width="Auto" >
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Country}" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
            </GridView>
        </myctrls:MyControl.SuggestionsView>
    </myctrls:MyControl>
</DataTemplate>
```

Same procedure for the `ProductsStyle`.

If you don't like the `ContentControl` wire-up approach, consider the creation of additional viewmodels that host then collections, like `AddressListViewModel`. This would allow you to handle the `DataTemplate` by `DataType` instead of resource key and explicit usage in `ContentControl`.

Comment: Your code is pretty close to my problem. Sorry that I did not come up with something similar. As the control is used for different types of items I defined some styles for them in a ResourceDictionary:

`<Style x:Key="AddressStyle" TargetType="{x:Type mubctrls:AutoCompleteLookup}" BasedOn="{StaticResource AutoCompleteLookupMainBaseStyle}">
        <Setter Property="MyView" Value="{DynamicResource AddressGridView}"/>        
    </Style>`

Comment: and
`<GridView x:Key="AddressGridView" x:Shared="False">
        <GridViewColumn Header="City"/>
        <GridViewColumn Header="Street"/>
    </GridView>`

Comment: This works at run time but under certain conditions at design time the XAML-Designer shows an error 'View can't be shared by more than one ListView'. In order to get rid of the problem I would like to introduce a dependency property of type DataTemplate. I would then wrap the GridView resources into DataTemplates and instead of assigning the GridView instances to the MyView property I would assign those DataTemplates to the new property. Within the OnApplyTemplate method of my user control I would like to create an instance that matches the data template and assign it to the MyView property.

Comment: @E812 Just think one level above. For example, make a `DataTemplate` for Address-Data, but on the `AutoCompleteLookup` level, not on the `AutoCompleteLookup.View` level. It shouldn't be to much extra code and it will work better because the View level is not suited to be a `DataTemplate`. Or alternatively, go one level down and work on `ItemTemplate` instead.

Comment: @E812 added an example with `DataTemplate`. You really have to give a full MCVE if thats not going in the right direction.

Comment: Yes, I think I will have to extract an MCVE out of our solution. The problem arises only on specific views. Unfortunately I have already left my workplace so I can not provide it until Monday.

Comment: I have uploaded an MCVE now: [link](https://1drv.ms/f/s!AvIly9wRk5oEqFRZMm9MV0k9Vpwx)
I also understand now why my approach of using a DataTemplate would not work. I had not recognized that I can't even define a GridView within a DataTemplate.

Comment: @E812 Basically the approach is really the same as I explained in my first edit. Did another edit at the bottom of my answer to match my code with your example.

Comment: Thank you for your latest edit. The ContentControl approach is really interesting. As the AutoCompleteLookup is more complex than in the MCVE I will not be able to use this approach directly but I think I can use it for the internal ListView. Also having the ability to let the ContentControl select its DataTemplate by the DataType and drop the explicit Style declaration would be a good enhancement over my actual implementation. Thank you for your good ideas and all the efforts you spend on my question.

Answer (score 0):

You could implement your own DataTemplateSelector, which then dynamically creates your one-time-use DataTemplate, roughly like that:

```
public DataTemplate GenerateTemplate() {
  var template = new DataTemplate();
  var p = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(Grid));
  p.SetValue(FrameworkElement.HorizontalAlignmentProperty, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
  p.SetValue(FrameworkElement.VerticalAlignmentProperty, VerticalAlignment.Center);
  ...
  template.VisualTree = p;
  return template;
}
```

Comment: I need to do it the other way around. I need to create an instance from a DataTemplate that is already assigned to a property of my customs control.